# Gettings reference to existing navigation controller in tab bar after receiving remote notification

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, push-notification

My app consists of following:

- Tab bar controller with 5 tabs (this is my init controller)
- each tab bar item has navigation controller and another view controllers further in

Now, I'm implementing skype-like chat (table view with contacts and chat as a detail view of this table view), which is currently residing in my second tab bar item, about 2 views deep in hierarchy.

When I receive remote notification, I want to preserve user navigation stack in all tabs, so instead of recreating tab bar in appdelegate, I just want to get reference of my navigation controller, that is in my second tab (so that I can modify it's navigation stack later on).

My problem here is, that I just can't get the reference. I got my tab bar like:

```
UITabBarController *myTabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

but then I don't have any clue what to do. I will be happy for any suggestion.

Comment: May be   (UINavigationController*)[myTabBar viewControllers][1] ?

Comment: Let me try :) But that would be too simple :D

Comment: Ok Im in love with you Leta0n.. please post it as an answer so that I can accept :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `(UINavigationController*)[myTabBar viewControllers][1]` :)

Comment: 4 more minutes and then I can accept.. Btw I was looking at viewcontrollers but I thought that it was exactly what it said... View controllers, not navigation controllers :) But thx alot man, you saved my day